# How to use DownloadManager with Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2, android-download-manager

We have a rest backend server which is used for downloading a file. Now we are doing it with retrofit and interceptor for getting download progress. We decided to use `DownloadManager` for this purpose because it is way more efficient for user.

When I checked some examples of it i found that it can get only URL for a file which can be downloaded. So how can we combine retrofit or restful api with `DownloadManager`?

Comment: To combine? I have no idea what you want as DownloadManager can perfectly file download a file without the help of anything.

Comment: @blackapps but it can download only from `URI` that point to the file right? But we have `GET` request with header for downloading

Comment: Well what does it matter? Just some queryparameters in an url? And what is a GET request with a header? And if a heder is neaded then for what?